# Browser is not adding cookie on some requests

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies, graphql, session-cookies

We are running an application (local app) inside another application ([moodle](https://moodle.org/)) as a plugin.
What happens is when our app tries to access the backend graphql it doesn't add the cookies but the cookie is available on `document.cookie` before the request is sent. Also before the app is opened in the iFrame there are few requests made from moodle to backend server and the browser adds the cookie to those request.

Following are the request headers

1. moodle -> backend

```
Host: graphql.app.home
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Referer: https://moodle.home:8443/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: cb_ltiid=s%3AF0FJpsc8bVe9ZqyLzgNgK7flKfGf4W7u.2GL43c7XLV11BzHXCS%2B7AvQKBAS9xg%2BNc7gaj264%2Bks
```

2. app (from moodle iFrame) -> backend

```
Host: graphql.app.home
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 118
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json
Origin: https://app.home
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://app.home/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Thanks for help

Comment: When you app is opened; did you check with Chrome dev tool the first requests have some warnings ? Usually this happening because of the set-cookie policies that are missing (same domain policy for instance)

Comment: I did check that, all of the configurations are right and I did not see any warnings or errors. what was weird was that it was working from the host app but would not work from the child app.

Answer (score 1):

It was issue with `fetch` not sending the header because of

> [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) won’t send cookies, unless you set the credentials init option.
> (Since Aug 25, 2017. The spec changed the default credentials policy
> to same-origin. Firefox changed since 61.0b13.)

solution was to pass `credentials: 'include'` to fetch options